# Как реализовать кнопки previous и next?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно переключать изображения на одном picturebox.
Этот код плохо работает, приходится по несколько раз нажимать, и не сразу срабатывает:

```
int count = 0;

        private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            if(count == 1)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.Dark_1;
            }
            if (count == 2)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.Dark_2;
            }
            if (count == 3)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.Dark_3;
            }
            if (count == 4)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.Dark_4;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count--;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.Dark_1;
            }
            if (count == 2)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.Dark_2;
            }
            if (count == 3)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.Dark_3;
            }
            if (count == 4)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.Dark_4;
            }
        }
```

Comment: ошибся, да WinForms

Comment: Вы пробовали использовать кнопки вместо пикчербоксов? Хотя в любом случае не понятен источник вашей проблемы, он где-то не в этом коде.

Comment: Возможно, в GUI-потоке производятся какие-то тяжёлые действия (вычисления), поэтому смена изображений делается не сразу, т. к. события клика ставятся в очередь сообщений и присовение Image делается тоже в GUI-потоке.

Comment: Если продолжить нажимать на Next, счётчик count станет намного больше 4. И потом при нажатии на Previous ничего не будет происходить, пока он не вернётся к нужным значениям. Добавьте проверки: `if (count > 4) count = 4;` - что-то наподобие

Comment: Эти ресурсы: `Dark_1`, `Dark_2`, и т. д. - они тяжёлые? Может, банально долго происходит загрузка с медленного (и загруженного другой работой) диска?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы Александр, проблема то ясна что count при каждом нажатии становится больше, вот я и спрашиваю как это нормально сделать